# Pass Doctrine Entity Array From Symfony Controller to Twig to Javascrip

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I want to pass two array `$homes_verified & $homes_not_verified` to javascript. I already tried to use `json_encode` but it's not working for me.

I want to pass this two array to `javascript` so that I can iterate using for loop and get values in `javascript` file.

```
   /**
     * @Route("/home/home-listing")
     */
    public function homeListingAction(Request $request) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $homes_verified = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Home')->findBy([
            'is_verified' => true
        ]);

        $queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Home')->createQueryBuilder('bp')
            ->andWhere('bp.is_verified LIKE :verified')
            ->setParameter('verified', false);
        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

        /**
         * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
         */
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $homes_not_verified = $paginator->paginate(
            $query, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1) /*page number*/,
            $request->query->getInt('limit', 1) /*limit per page*/
        );

        dump($homes_verified);

        return $this->render('HomeListing/homeListing.html.twig', [
            'homes_verified' => $homes_verified,
            'homes_not_verified' => $homes_not_verified,
            "res" => json_encode($userArray),
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go this way. :)

PHP is  server side , js is client side language . Connection  beetwen them is possible in a way that you trying to do - but it's really not recomended (it 'll give you headache ).  Try to separate  php from js  as  much as you can .

Pass data to js  using AJAX ,
create another route (for example /api/homes_veryfied ) and on this route return  in response your data in json format  , for example

`return new JsonResponse(array($homes_veryfied));`

in  js (in view) call created  route and get data  from there 
for example  you can use jquery  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/